# I want insert record into database but I get undefined index I write this code .php file

Tags: php, knockout.js

```
<?php

    $action = $_POST['insert'];
    $info_array = array();

    $ItemCode = $_POST['ItemCode'];
    $ItemName = $_POST['ItemName'];
    $Quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];
    $Rate = $_POST['Rate'];
    $Total = $_POST['Total'];

    echo $SqlPurchdtls = "insert into tblpurcdetails (itemId,itemQty,itemRate,TotalAmt)values
                ('" . $ItemCode . "','" . $Quantity . "','" . $Rate . "','" . $Total . "')";
    $ResultPurchdtls = mysql_query($SqlPurchdtls);

    //build the array that will store the item records
    $info_array[] = array( 'idItem' => $idItem, 'ItemName' => $ItemName, 'Quantity' => $Quantity , 'Rate' => $Rate , 'Total' =>$Total);

    echo json_encode($info_array); //convert the array to JSON string

    ?>
```

In this code value not inserted.I created database but value not posted.How to store values in the json array

Comment: what is undefined index name and can u post error here. after echo query run it directly in phpmyadmin and see what happens

Comment: Where is $idItem defined/assigned a value?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but too long for a comment:

First of all, **never** put $_POST (or any other) variables directly in your query. Always use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).
Secondly, `mysql_xxx` functions are deprecated. Please use `mysqli_xxx`.

Now that we have that out of the way, from the information you have given, it is impossible to see why the insert is not working. It also is not clear what your question is. Do you need help with the insert into database or help populating a json array?

Please provide the mysql error message and echo the generated sql. Are you connected to the right database? etc..

(Free tip: you can use [compact](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) to create the array $info_array more cleanly)